# Chinese Remainder Thoerem - Is it possible to solve a system of congruences that are not coprime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

$x \equiv 1\mod3$
$x \equiv 2\mod 9$
Is it possible to solve this system of congruences?

Answer (score 2):

$x\equiv 2 \bmod 9\implies x\equiv 2 \bmod 3$

in general $x\equiv a \bmod nk \implies x \equiv a \bmod n$

Comment: There's still no multiplicative inverse for where 3 * Y1 = 1 mod 3 though. How do I apply CRT here?

Comment: You can't. There does not exists a number $x$ such that $x \equiv 1\mod 3$ and $x \equiv 2\mod 3$